# Is there a way to get form values with onChange using Shadcn Form & Zod?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, zod

I have implemented a form to sign in using zod for client-side validation. I wanted to also add a password strength display for which i decided to try out react-password-strength-bar.

The functionality is simple, you just render the PasswordStrengthBar and pass-in the password value as a prop:

```js
import PasswordStrengthBar from "react-password-strength-bar";

<PasswordStrengthBar password={pass} />
```

While trying so, I've noticed I cannot use onChange event listener for Input field, because apparently it is already used. Same goes with ref, where I would have used useEffect that would trigger every time the input value changes.

I found that I can get the value using form.getValues("password") it feels wrong to use form function as a dependency which I would then use as a value for PasswordStrengthBar. I have also tried placing form in useEffect, but it seems like it does not update with input change.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could make this work?

Full code:

```js
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NotificationContext from "@/lib/context/notification-context";
import defaultNotification from "@/lib/locale/default-notification";
import PasswordStrengthBar from "react-password-strength-bar";
import { authFormSchema } from "@/lib/formSchema";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import SubmitButton from "../ui/custom-ui/submit-btn";

export default function AuthForm() {
  const notifCtx = useContext(NotificationContext);
  const [pass, setPass] = useState<string>("");

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof authFormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(authFormSchema),
    defaultValues: { email: "", password: "" }
  });
  const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;

  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof authFormSchema>) {
    // ✅ This will be type-safe and validated.
    notifCtx.setNotification(defaultNotification.pending);

    const res = await fetch("/api/auth/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...values })
    });
    const { err, msg } = await res.json();

    notifCtx.setNotification(defaultNotification[err ? "error" : "success"](msg));
    !err && form.reset();
    return;
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setPass(form.getValues("password"));
  }, [form]);

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-2">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="email"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="john@doe.com" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="password"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel className="">Password</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input placeholder="password123" type="password" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        <PasswordStrengthBar password={pass} />

        <div className="">
          <SubmitButton
            className="w-full my-4 dark:bg-white dark:hover:bg-primary dark:text-black dark:hover:text-white"
            isLoading={isLoading}
            text="Sign up"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:
I forgot that you can use onChangeCapture since it doesn't contain any child elements to trigger more actions.

```js
<Input placeholder="password123" onChangeCapture={e => setPass(e.currentTarget.value)} type="password" {...field} />
```